# AngularJS render content in a textarea after a click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I'm using Angular JS to try and update the value of a `<textarea>` using a $http request after a link is clicked to fetch some content in my controllers.js as shown here:

```
$scope.setDocument = function(docId) {
  $http.get('docs/' + docId + '.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.content = data.docData;
    console.log('setting document: ' + data.docData);
  });
}
```

the log statement shows the right document data, but the result is not rendered in the text area on the browser:

```
<textarea id="main-writer" ng-model="content" class="row-fluid" autofocus="true" cols="48" rows="24"></textarea>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide more information, simple example here worked http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/KjtNU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `ng-model="content"` not `"docData"`

EDIT: You might want to do $scope.$apply(); after setting the new content. Although I don't think it is necessary but worth a try. There is a nice Chrome extension for inspecting AngularJS scopes and bindings. You might want to use that to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what's happening, but my setDocument function looks like it isn't being bound to the scope.  I'll keep messing with it.

Comment: The problem ended up being in the link I clicked to call the function `<a href="#" ng-click="setDocument(doc.id)">Open</a>` removing the # solved the problem. It says so in the documentation here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:a